# How do i call an oracle stored procedure with XmlType IN parameter in Jmeter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jmeter, xmltype

I am trying to test an oracle stored procedure that takes 1 IN parameter and 1 OUT parameter of type XmlType. How do i call this stored procedure using JDBC Request Object in jmeter ? I have tried using SQLXml int value of 2009 as parameter type, but keep getting invalid column type.

See sample input below

sample procedure below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1_PRC
(
   Request_obj1    IN    XMLTYPE,
   response_obj2   OUT   XMLTYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (‘MyResult’);
END;
```

Comment: How big is the XML?  If less than 32K then maybe write a wrapper pl/sql proc that takes a varchar2 as a parameter instead and calls your xml function.